# Find the necessary and sufficient condition on $x$ so given matrix becomes orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $N \ge 2$ and let $x$ be a non zero column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Find the necessary and sufficient condition on $x$ so that $I - 2xx^{T}$ is orthogonal.

I know this question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143695/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-the-matrix-a-i-2xxt-to-be-orthogonal), but my main issue is that I am not able to understand why $x{x^t} = x^{t}x$ Because  while $xx^t$ is a $n *n$ matrix the other value is actually a constant.

Can someone please explain this to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in the link you posted does not say $xx^t=x^tx$, it just says that $xx^txx^t = x(x^tx)x^t = (x^tx)xx^t$ because $x^tx$ is a scalar.